# Unable to send and retrieve message using QuickBlox in ionic 2 using javascript SDK

Tags: angular, ionic2, quickblox

I am new to ionic 2 and having problem to integrate quickBlox in ionic 2

1. I am unable to send and retrieve message in 1-1 chat app using
   quickBlox in ionic 2 while the dialog is creating successfully.
2. How to make sure that the message is posted?
3. How to set onMessageListener

   ```
   import * as quickblox from "quickblox";

   CREDENTIALS:any = {
      appId: 57065,
      authKey: 'xxxxx',
      authSecret: 'yyyy'
   };

   user:any = {
     id: 27139599,
     login: 'abc@gmail.com',
     pass: 'pass@123'
   };

   //initialize QuickBlox

   ngOnInit(){
        quickblox.init(this.CREDENTIALS.appId, this.CREDENTIALS.authKey, this.CREDENTIALS.authSecret);
    }


    quickblox.createSession(`enter code here`{login: user.email, password: user.pass},(err, result) => {
     if (result){
      quickblox.chat.connect(
         {userId: user.user_id, password:user.pass},(err, roster) => {
              if (err){
                 console.log("Connection Error :enter code here ",err);
              } else {
                console.log("Connected to quickblox");
                }
              });
     }      
   });


   sendMessage(emp){
     var msg = {
           type: 'chat',
           body: "How are you today?",
           extension: {
             save_to_history: 1,
           }
         };

       let opponentId = emp;
       quickblox.chat.send(opponentId, msg);
   }
   ```